# Bypass reCAPTCHA in selenium web driver for Google search automation

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape news link appear in google search page.

```
27 Dec 2017 – 24 Feb 2018
All results
Clear
Page 2 of 16 results (0.38 seconds) 

Nirav Modi, the jewellery designer at the centre of Rs ...

businesstoday.in
https://www.businesstoday.in › LATEST › Corporate
15-Feb-2018 — Union Bank of India, Allahabad Bank and Axis Bank are reported to have offered credit based on letters of undertaking (LOUs) issued by PNB. Published on: Feb 15 ...

Auto Expo 2018: Tata Motors unveils H5X SUV, 45X ...

businesstoday.in
https://www.businesstoday.in › Auto
07-Feb-2018 — Nifty Bank can see significant upside; ICICI Bank, Axis Bank, SBI, BoB and Canara Bank may do well. RECOMMENDED. New vs old Parliament building: Government ...

Implications of 10% long term capital gains tax proposed in ...

businesstoday.in
https://www.businesstoday.in › ... › Columns
03-Feb-2018 — The Finance Bill 2018 has further proposed significant changes in these taxation provisions relating to long term capital gain on transfer of equity shares ...
```

code for scrapping link

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:\Business_today\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(urls[3])
time.sleep(10)

link = set()
i = 1
while(True):
    if i%10 == 0:
        print('pages done'+str(i))
    try:
        myDiv = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'v7W49e')
        t=myDiv.get_attribute("outerHTML")
        html_soup_object = BeautifulSoup(t, 'html.parser')
        find_element2 = html_soup_object.find_all('div')

        for ele in find_element2:
            for a_elm in ele.find_all("a"):
                # print(a_elm.attrs["href"])
                if a_elm.attrs["href"].startswith('https://www.livemint.com/'):
                    link.add(a_elm.attrs["href"])
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            link_element = driver.find_element(By.ID,'pnnext')
            link_element.click()  
            i = i+ 1
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
driver.quit()


links = list(link)
# res2 = [links[i] for i in range(len(links)) if i % 2 != 0]
print('total links ='+str(len(links)))
total += links
print("total home_page links = "+str(len(total)))
time.sleep(10)
```

this block will navigate to next page in google search
try:
link_element = driver.find_element(By.ID,'pnnext')
link_element.click()

after some searches it shows reCaptha and web driver stops

Is there any way to bypass  this reCaptcha